# How to create documentation for ANTLR?

Tags: antlr4

I'm creating a language via ANTLR that I'd like to publish for user to use.

Are there a tool to create automated or semi-automated documentation for my language ?

I'm looking to make a documentation like

- https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/index.html

Comment: I've never seen such a thing/tool.

Comment: Like Bart, I don't know of any tool to generate anything close to full documentation (probably because, there's really not all the information you'd need in just the grammar).  But take a look at the VS Code ANTLR plugin.  It can generate "Railroad Diagrams" documenting all of your rules, and I suspect that they'd be a nice addition to your documentation.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, just like Bart and Mike said there was no such tool that could help in the process of creating a documentation simply.